# FILE_URI empty in phonegap getpicture() for video mediatype

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have an issue with phonegap getPicture function. Everything run perfectly when I pick a picture, but when it comes to video the onSuccess function retrieve me a empty file_uri. The thing is when I run the app with : *phonegap serve* I can pick a video without any issue, but with a apk build the onSuccess function get me a blank file_uri...

```
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,
  {
    quality:50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.VIDEO
  });          

  function onSuccess(videoURI) { 
    console.log(videoURI);//this is empty 
  }
```

I thought this was a permission problem but why does it work with a picture but not a video.

Thank you for your help !